# Ruby count items by date

Tags: ruby, date, parsing

I have an array of dates e.g.

```
Fri Jan 28 10:13:19 UTC 2011
Thu Jan 27 16:57:59 UTC 2011
Thu Jan 27 16:41:21 UTC 2011
Wed Jan 26 09:20:48 UTC 2011
Mon Jan 24 16:19:48 UTC 2011
Fri Jan 21 11:45:34 UTC 2011
Fri Jan 21 11:42:19 UTC 2011
```

How can I group them so the output is as hash with the count of items each day:

```
Friday 28 => 1
Thursday 27 => 2
Wednesday 26 => 1
Monday 24 => 1
Friday 21 => 2
```

Comment: Are you looking to group them by day specifically or timestamp as listed above your output hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, to put kurumi's solution more verbosely and using Jimmy's strftime:

```
histogram = dates.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |hist, date|
  hist[date.strftime('%A %d')] += 1
  hist 
end.sort_by{|date, count| date.split(' ').last}.reverse
```

give us:

```
Friday 28: 1
Thursday 27: 2
Wednesday 26: 1
Monday 24: 1
Friday 21: 2
```

OK?

Answer (score 1):

```
@things.group_by {|thing| thing.strftime "%A %d" }.each do |key, group|
  puts "#{key} => #{group.size}"
end
```

`%A` is the full weekday name and `%d` is the day of the month

I can't test this currently but I *think* it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
s=a.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |h,y|
    z=y.split
    h[ z[0]+z[2] ]+=1
    h
end
```