# How do count until a specific created_at date in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a Relationships class and i'd like to spit out a list of how many friends a user had on a specific date range (between today and 4 weeks ago).

I've tried the following in an html.erb but it doesn't appear to be working:

```
<table>
<% rightnow = DateTime.now.to_i %>
<% twentyeight = Time.at(rightnow).to_time - 28.days %>
<% twght = twentyeight.to_i %>
<% (twght..rightnow).step(1.day).map do |time| %>
  <tr><th><%= Time.at(time).strftime("%a %b %y") %></th></tr>
  <tr><td><%= Relationship.where(:follower_id => @user.id, :created_at => from .. to time ).count %></td></tr>
</table>
```

I suspect the answer might be along the lines of this one but i don't know how to implement it... [Ruby count items by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828920/ruby-count-items-by-date)

Also, as i'm still grappling with MVC, how might i clean up the code? I tried creating a method in my users_controller but was unable to succesfully call it.

Cheers.

Edit:

Here is another attempt at it, which works. Feedback welcome:

```
<tfoot>
<% before = DateTime.now - 28.days%>
<% following =  Relationship.where(:followed_id => @user.id) %>
<tr>
<% before.step(before + 28, 1) do |time| %>
<th><%= time.strftime("%a %b #{time.day.ordinalize}") %></th>
<% end %>
```

<% before.step(before + 28, 1) do |time| %>

```
<td>
<%= following.all(:conditions => ["created_at < ?", time.end_of_day]).count %>
</td><% end %>
</tr>
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to skip the part where we pop the 'why?' stack.  So let's say you're looking at the index view of the Relationships controller, for the sake of argument.  Most of that code belongs in the controller, so let's start with the easy case:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_user #whatever you do to load your currently logged in user
  def index
    @relationships = @user.relationships.where(:created_at => 28.days.ago..Date.today)
  end
end
```

in your view:

```
<table>
  <tr><th><%= Time.at(time).strftime("%a %b %y") %></th></tr>
  <tr><td><%= @relationships.count %></td></tr>
</table>
```

This will show how many relationships you created in the last 28 days.  This doesn't get you to your running tally though, so let's refactor the design a bit by adding a method to your model:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  #... skip other stuff
  def self.relationship_count_for_days(start_date, end_date)
    where(:created_at => start_date..end_date).count
  end
end
```

then your view will become:

```
<table>
  <% 28.downto(1) do |days_ago| %>
    <tr><th><%= days_ago.days.ago.to_time.strftime("%a %b %y") %></th></tr>
    <tr><td><%= @relationships.relationship_count_for_days(28.days.ago, days_ago.days.ago) %></td></tr>
  <% end
</table>
```

Comment: Cheers @karmajunkie and boris. I'll try that now. In the meantime, i had come up with another (non MVC-friendly) solution. I've edited in to my question if you can give me some feedback on it.

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented a version of your code and it's working great. But i think im getting more queries than with the code i posted in my edit. Is there a way to reduce the number of queries with your code?

Comment: i'd have to see what you're actually implementing, but my advice is not to worry too much about the queries.  When it becomes a bottleneck, solve the problem.  That's usually a hard thing for newer rails devs to wrap their head around, and there's no reason to get sloppy, but optimize the things that matter.  This, for example, is an easily cacheable view that might run a few extra queries the first time, but will run 0 each time after that, until the cache expires or is invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to do next:
In your controller:

```
@relationships = Relationship.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", your_start_date, your_end_date)
```

and then in your view you can iterate through @relationships and builld your presentation

*your_start_date - can be `Time.now - 28.days`